# dotLess files not always loaded on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dotless

in my project, I'm using dotLess to define css. Everything works fine, but for some reason, sometimes (usually after project build or server restart, but not always) less files are not loaded (IIS returns 404 error). If I refresh my page few times, less file is loaded and after that usually everything is ok.
I know, that there is another question about dotLess and ISS 404 error, but solution proposed there (adding mimeMap to web.config) did not help to resolve this issue on my site.

Does anyone know what might be causing this errors? Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules>
  <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="StyleSheetManager" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControl" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="LessStyleCompiler" path="*.less" verb="*" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core"/>
</handlers>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is a fragment of web.config, that registers dotLess. My application is rather medium size, also I don't think that this may be due to my computer being slow, as the same thing is happening on many machines, no matter how powerful it is.

Comment: The configuration looks fine to me. I'll have to investigate further. For the moment i'd suggest pre-compiling your less and during development you could use the ``dotless.Compiler.exe --watch``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of those issues with `less` files not always being sent to browser, we decided to compile them on design-time. To achieve this we are currently using `Chirpy` plugin to VS2010 which handles compiling `less` files and minimizing them, giving in output plain `css` files. This way everything works.

Thats a pity, though, that the handler had some issues, this would make our work much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe post your web.config?

It could be an issue of your computer being slow to load the HttpHandlers? I don't really know. 
How large is your application?

Have you thought about using the dotless.Compiler.exe --watch feature?